# rtai no such file or directory error compiling

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, rtai

I trying to compile a .cpp program from Debian 6. I have a working makefile, which only works with .c archives, but I need to compile my program on .cpp. So here its the makefile:

```
#
# Build the examples.
#

# The great thing about GNU Make is that it knows so much about your     lifestyle, you don't need to
# tell it the obvious things. This file is a minimal makefile.

# You run this makefile by typing `make' in the directory with the   makefile

# You can find out more about make by typing `info make'.

# This tells Make that we need to link everything with the robot code:
LDLIBS=/usr/lib/robot.a

CC=gcc

# This variable has a handy copy of all the things we aim to produce
EXEC= read_sensor turn_on_and_off control_joint cerrar_mano

# Thses are all the things we need to compile:
all: ${EXEC}  

CFLAGS=-I/usr/realtime/include/ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE - rtai_types -rtai_lxrt

# Make now looks around the directory, finds the read_sensor.c and
# turn_on_and_off.c files, works out it can compile them into the
# read_sensor and turn_on_and_off executables, and does so!

# However, for the kernel modules, we need to do a bit more.
rt_control: rt_control.o
ld -E -O2 -r -o $@ $^ 

# This is an example of making a binary from several object files, as an   example only!
fred: bert.o jim.o
ld -E -O2 -o $@ $^ 

# We need to tell the compiler quite a lot about where to find the right  header files
rt_control.o: control.c
$(CC) -c -O2  -DREALTIME -DRTAI_3  -I./include/ -I. -I../  -isystem     /usr/realtime/include/  -isystem /usr/src/linux/include   -o $@ $^


# We put some housekeeping in here:

# This target is used to remove intermediate files Make produces.
clean:; rm -f *.o
# This target is used to remove output files Make produces as well.
realclean: clean
rm -f ${EXEC}
```

So when I write on terminal make myprogramname.cpp This is what i get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:24:44: error: rtai_types.h: No such file or  directory
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:38:23: error: rtai_lxrt.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:168: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:178: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
In file included from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/robot.h:194: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
/usr/include/robot/robot.h:244: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
Programa_Hand2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Programa_Hand2.cpp:18: error: expected initializer before 'printf'
Programa_Hand2.cpp:19: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
hand@hand-cartagena:~/Desktop/Joaquin/examples$ make Programa_Hand2
g++     Programa_Hand2.cpp  /usr/lib/robot.a -o Programa_Hand2
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:24:44: error: rtai_types.h: No such file or  directory
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:38:23: error: rtai_lxrt.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:168: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/robot/robot.h:38,
             from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/sensor.h:178: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
In file included from Programa_Hand2.cpp:4:
/usr/include/robot/robot.h:194: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
/usr/include/robot/robot.h:244: error: 'RTIME' does not name a type
Programa_Hand2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Programa_Hand2.cpp:18: error: expected initializer before 'printf'
Programa_Hand2.cpp:19: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [Programa_Hand2] Error 1
```

Also tried with gcc -o Programa_Hand2 Programa_Hand2.cpp and getting the same error, I think its something I have to change with the makefile but dont know what its wrong there
Any ideas? Im new to programming and linux, so Im getting a bit mad with this, because I need the program to be compiled on c++, and I compiled it and works properly on c. Thanks for your help!

Edit: doing some research from the internet, seems to be that RTAI doesnt support C++; so there is any way to compile it in C++? Also, my #includes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <robot/robot.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "RobotConfig.h"
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In short you need to use the command g++ not gcc for C++ files.

You need to compile C++ files with a C++ compiler not a C compiler and there are differences.

The command for GNU C++ Compiler is g++ assuming you have it installed. That is likely since you seem to have a C compiler.

Add a variable to your Makefile named CXX and set it equal to g++. Then compile your C++ code using the CXX variable as the command instead of the CC variable.

$(CXX) -o <.output file name> <.cpp files go here>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I`ll try what you say!